# Does Xamarin/MonoDroid offer BBM api?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android, bb-messenger

Is there a BBM API available through Xamarin?

I would like to automate BBM functionality on Android using MonoDroid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AFAIK there is no BBM API for iOS or Android.